# Maximal growth condition for embedding of Orlicz spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, orlicz-spaces

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ be a Young's function, and let $L^2_\Phi(0,1)$ denote the Orlicz space. Consider the continuous embedding $H^2_0(0,1)\hookrightarrow L^2_\Phi(0,1)$. Should there be a growth agrowth condition on $\Phi$ for the embedding to be true? I know the case when $H^1_0(0,1)$ is replaced, which is basically the Trudinger's  inequality.

Comment: I think your question would get more attention/answers if you would include the definition of Orlicz spaces and their norm in the question. Since they are not as common as say $L^p$ or Sobolev spaces not everyone is familiar with them.